# If statement that ensures round number

Tags: java, if-statement, int

Can I make an if statement in Java like the one below, that ensures that a number is round?

```
if(some number int)
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes

```
System.out.println(6.0 % 1 == 0);
```

prints

```
true
```

while

```
System.out.println(6.1 % 1 == 0);
```

prints

```
false
```

As the [JLS specifies](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3) for the remainder operation for floating point numbers :

> In the remaining cases, where neither an infinity, nor a zero, nor NaN is involved, the floating-point remainder r from the division of a dividend n by a divisor d is defined by the mathematical relation r = n - (d · q) where q is an integer that is negative only if n/d is negative and positive only if n/d is positive, and whose magnitude is as large as possible without exceeding the magnitude of the true mathematical quotient of n and d.

Therefore, if `n` is the number you wish to test and `d` is 1, the remainder r is `r = n - q` for some integer `q`. Therefore, if the remainder `r` is `0`, `n = q` for some integer `q`, so your tested number `n` is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to check if a number is an int:

```
public boolean isObjectInteger(Object o) { return o instanceof Integer; }
```

Should do the job.

Comment: This check if the object is class Integer, and I don't think this is what he wants...

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, using [`Math.rint`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#rint-double-):

```
if(x == Math.rint(x))
```

Comment: Thanks everyone and sorry about my first explain.